# how do i convert datagridview cell click event to DevExpress Grid Control

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, datagridview, devextreme

The program i have create for "Inventory system". And also i have create **GridControl** from **Devexpress** Tools. how do i convert this code to Devexpress gridcontrol.. 
please refer attached image [GridControl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Vq69.png)

```
 private void dgvinvoicesummary_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int id = e.RowIndex;
            DataGridViewRow row = dgvinvoicesummary.Rows[id];
            int ddl1 = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[2].Value.ToString());

            if (dgvinvoicesummary.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Update")
            {
                invoiceSummary Obj = new invoiceSummary
                {                      
                    CustomerName = row.Cells["customerName"].Value.ToString(),
                    InvoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells["invoiceId"].Value.ToString()),
                    IssueDate = row.Cells["issue_date"].Value.ToString(),
                    DueDate = row.Cells["due_date"].Value.ToString(),
                    Status = row.Cells["Status"].Value.ToString()

                 };
                frmAddinvoice fm = new frmAddinvoice(Obj);              
                fm.ShowDialog();
                this.Close();
                GetInvoiceSummaryData();                    
            }      
            if (dgvinvoicesummary.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "delete")
            {
                DeleteInvoiceSummaryRow(ddl1);                                    
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Answer should be like this

```
  private void gridView1_RowCellClick(object sender, RowCellClickEventArgs e)
    {

        int id = e.RowHandle;
        DataRow row = gridView1.GetDataRow(id);
        int ddl1 = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id, "invoiceId").ToString());

        if (e.Column.Name=="ActionUpdate")
        {
            invoiceSummary Obj = new invoiceSummary
               {

                   CustomerName = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id, "customerName").ToString(),
                   InvoiceID = Convert.ToInt32(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"invoiceId").ToString()),
                   IssueDate = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"issue_date").ToString(),
                   DueDate = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"due_date").ToString(),
                   Status = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Status").ToString(),
                   PrivateNote = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"privateNotes").ToString(),
                   PadiAmount = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Amount_Paid").ToString()),
                   Balance = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Balance").ToString()),
                   PaymentType = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"paymentType").ToString(),
                   DateOfPayment = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"DateOfPayment").ToString(),
                   TotalDiscount = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"TotalDiscount").ToString()),
                   PackagingAmount = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"PackagingAmount").ToString()),
                   CustomerNote = gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"CustomerNote").ToString(),
                   TaxTotalAmount = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Tax_Amount").ToString()),
                   Valuedata = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Amount").ToString()),
                   TotalSubAmount = Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(id,"Total_Amount").ToString()),

               };
            frmAddinvoice fm = new frmAddinvoice(Obj);
            fm.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
            GetInvoiceSummaryData();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("");
        }


    }
```